# [Python argparse]set the behaviour of an argument to be interactive if no value is given

Tags: python, default-value, argparse, interactive

I wonder if it is possible to change the behaviour of an argument depending if a value was given or not.

Typically, I want to provide an interactive way to enter a password.

example usages:

> $script.py => use the default argument value for argument 'p'
>
> $script.py -p mypass => use 'mypass' as value for 'p'
>
> $script.py -p => get password interactively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", nargs='?', const="mypass", default="default")

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.p:
    print args.p
```

You can then check for the value of p and get the password interactively

Answer (score 3):

A simple class:

```
class AskUser:
    def __init__(self, type, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.type = type
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __call__(self, value):
        if value == '':
            value = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self.type(value)
```

which you can plug directly into argparse:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('user', nargs='?', type=AskUser(str, input, 'Enter user name: '), default='')
parser.add_argument('file', nargs='?', type=AskUser(Path, filedialog.asksaveasfilename,
    title='Select a file', filetypes=(('CSV files', '*.csv'),), defaultextension='.csv'), default='')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: where does AskUser come from?